# File browser panel inside Cocoa app

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is it possible to create a panel inside my app that shows files in a directory? I drew a mockup. The red rectangle is the file browser panel and the outside area is my app.

[image]

Comment: In what way is this different from what NSOpenPanel does?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `NSCollectionView`, each of your `NSCollectionViewItem` being filled with information fetched from a `NSFileManager` like the file names and icons?

Comment: I need to keep other functionality like right clicking on a file to bring up the context menu in tact.